# cast from float to nsdecimalnumber always fails swift

Tags: swift3

I am reading my data through a web service that returns a percentage as a string and I need to format it properly in my app.  Currently I receive an error message that reads "Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads".

Suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

```
            if let dUnInsured = result[0]["UnInsured"] as? String, let doubleNum = Double(dUnInsured) {
                let sUnInsured = dollarFormatter.string(from: (NSDecimalNumber(Decimal(doubleNum))))!
                self.inUninsured.text = sUnInsured
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this way.

```
if let dUnInsured = result[0]["UnInsured"] as? String, let doubleNum = Double(dUnInsured) {
    let sUnInsured = dollarFormatter.string(from: (NSNumber(value: doubleNum)))!
    self.inUninsured.text = sUnInsured
}
```

Comment: Must I do something to enable DecimalNumber?  I not get an error stating "Use of unresolved identifier 'DecimalNumber'"

Comment: @AETechAdm It's typo mistake forgot to add `(NS)` before `DecimalNumber`, check the edited answer.

Comment: `if let dUnInsured = result[0]["UnInsured"] as? String, let doubleNum = Double(dUnInsured) {
                    let sUnInsured = dollarFormatter.string(from: (NSDecimalNumber(Decimal(doubleNum))))!
                    self.inUninsured.text = sUnInsured
               } `

Comment: @AETechAdm Edit your question with your current code where you are getting this error.

Comment: @AETechAdm On which line you are getting error? And what is type of `dollarFormatter`?

Comment: I am getting the error on line that begins with ` sUnInsured = dollarFormater.string`.  Here is the code for dollarFormatter: `let dollarFormatter = NumberFormatter()
                dollarFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
                dollarFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") as Locale!`

Comment: @AETechAdm And what is type of `dollarFormatter` you haven't mentioned that.

Comment: `let dollarFormatter = NumberFormatter()
                dollarFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
                dollarFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") as Locale`

Comment: @AETechAdm Then there is no need to `convert float/double` to `NSDecimalNumber` instead of that you simply need to use `NSNumber` . Check my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your help that fixes the problem.

Comment: @AETechAdm Welcome mate :)